# CloudSQL "pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host" pmm-agent

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, percona

I'm trying to setup a pmm-agent to monitor my db at GCP but I'm getting this error:
`pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host`

The user is `postgres` and I can connect trhough `psql`, but when I'm using it trought a service in machine, this fails. Already check conections for db and network.

Comment: What is the rest of the error message?

Comment: db=cloudsqladmin,user=pmm FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "10.128.0.2", user "pmm", database "cloudsqladmin", SSL off

Comment: The 'SSL off' is probably the core of the problem.  It is likely that it is trying to connect with ssl, failing for some interesting reason, then trying to fall back to no ssl, and failing because the server does not allow that.